# Alternative match function perl

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have a file that has a number on each line.

```
1
7
9
15
22
29
30
30  <--
30  <--
30  <--
40
42
49
50
50  <--
50  <--
55
```

I can't allow numbers to appear more than a single time. When a duplicate is found, it should replace it with the next unused number instead.

```
1
7
9
15
22
29
30
31  <--
32  <--
33  <--
40
42
49
50
51  <--
52  <--
55
```

If I put in a column from a table to a perl, awk sed bash script...how could I come up with that solution? Any idea would be amazing...

Comment: Have you tried anything and getting some error? Please post that

Comment: Try [`List::MoreUtils::uniq`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#uniq-LIST).. Example: `perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -E '@a=uniq(1,1,2,2,3); say "@a"'`

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, That doesn't produce the requested output.

Comment: Assuming a number on each line: `perl -nle'print $x = $. == 1 || $_ > $x ? $_ : $x+1'`

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, you are right.. I misread the question.

Comment: Please vote to reopen now that the question has been clarified some :)

Comment: Thanks, @ikegami, now with the updated edit to the question it's clear I had the wrong idea --- still I should have seen the output didn't match and not jumped in.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bash 4 solution, problem is that  bash does not have a sort builtin.

**Edit**
Trying to follow the comments, maybe this is what is required?

```
declare -A assoc
while read key
do
    while [[ -n ${assoc[$key]} ]]
    do
        (( key++ ))
    done  

    assoc[$key]=1

done < vector.txt

oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
echo "${!assoc[*]}" | sort -n > out.txt
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

Contents of vector.txt:

```
1
7
9
15
22
29
30
30
30
30
40
42
49
50
50
50
55
```

Contents of out.txt:

```
1
7
9
15
22
29
30
31
32
33
40
42
49
50
51
52
55
```

Perl solution which does the same thing:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %assoc;
my $fname = 'vector.txt';

open(my $in, $fname) or die "Unable to open '$fname': $!";
while (my $key = <$in>) {

    chomp($key);
    $key++ while exists $assoc{$key};
    $assoc{$key} = undef;

}
close $in;

my @output = sort {$a <=> $b} keys(%assoc);
local $" = "\n";
open(my $out, '>', 'out.txt') or die "Unable to open 'out.txt': $!";
print $out "@output\n";
close $out;
```

Comment: it shoudl not be only 30 bur as in the line above with 30 plus 1 30 plus 2 30 plus 3...can you edi?

Comment: @sdji:  edit done, how is that now?

Answer (score 1):

Use [unique](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html) in R:

```
> v<-c(1,7,9,15,22,29,30,30,30,30,40,42,49,50,50,50,55)
> unique(v)

[1]  1  7  9 15 22 29 30 40 42 49 50 55
```

Or in a perl script, use a hash:

```
my @list = qw(1 7 9 15 22 29 30 30 30 30 40 42 49 50 50 50 55);

my %nums;

$nums{$_}++ foreach @list;

say foreach sort {$a <=> $b } keys %nums;
```

Comment: it would be good if it could do it for any input file in which the numbers are 1 number per ro....

Comment: @sdji: Take it as an exercise. Don't ask for spoonfeeding.

Comment: the output shoudl also 1 column with a numbe rin every ro

Comment: @Chankey the q ist really clear and reproducable i use only best pracice notati...that shoudl nto bee too diff...have youa  sugg?

Comment: @sdji - The question is not clear on those points. Please edit it to reflect what you're actually trying to do

Comment: the unique answ is just wrong...the replica has to be repaete...it needs to be 30, 30 plus 1 30 plus 2 not only 30...the answer is wro....